# HTML Octothorpe in VB

Tags: html, vb.net, hashtag

I am trying to open my html document through VB. Code below:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Button1.Click
    Process.Start("file:///C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Final/index.html#SL")
End Sub
```

My problem is every time it opens the html document it does not go to the Octothorpe(#SL), it only opens this part file:///C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Final/index.html  without the #SL.

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: That's called a fragment, not a hashtag (the character is called Octothorpe)

Comment: I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Process.Start on iexplore.exe, so that you can specify the URL specifically as its argument. You need to specify the default browser for this to work.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", @"file:///C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Final/index.html#SL")
```

Comment: I removed the "@" and seems to be working fine. Thank you